# Add controls dynamically to RadMultiPage

Tags: c#, telerik, radgrid, multipage

I have the following piece of code for radControls.

```
 <telerik:RadTabStrip ID="RadTabStripControl" runat="server"  MultiPageID="RadMultiPageControl"         SelectedIndex="0" OnTabClick="RadTabStripControl_TabClick">
<Tabs>
    <telerik:RadTab Text="Test" Value="TestReport" TabIndex="0" Selected="true" >
    </telerik:RadTab>
</Tabs>
</telerik:RadTabStrip>

<telerik:RadMultiPage ID="RadMultiPageControl" RenderSelectedPageOnly="true" runat="server"      SelectedIndex="0" CssClass="TestSkin"  Height="95%" >
 <telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageViewTest"  TabIndex="0"    runat="server"  Height="95%">
             <telerik:RadGrid ID="GridTest"  runat="server"  Height="100%" Skin="MyCustomSkin" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false"   PageSize="50"
                    OnPageSizeChanged="GridTest_PageSizeChanged" Width="100%" OnSortCommand="GridTest_SortCommand"  OnPageIndexChanged="GridTest_PageIndexChanged"
                    EnableLinqExpressions="false" OnNeedDataSource="GridTest_NeedDataSource"  OnItemCommand="GridTest_OnItemCommand" OnItemCreated="GridTest_ItemCreated" >

            </telerik:RadGrid>
 </telerik:RadPageView>
```

and following is my backend code:

```
if (DtPreference.Rows.Count > 0) // getting 7 rows 
        { 
            Int16 i = 1;
            foreach (DataRow dr in DtPreference.Rows)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["Test"].ToString()))
                {
                    RadTab tabTemp = new RadTab();
                    tabTemp.Text = dr["Test"].ToString();
                    tabTemp.Value = dr["Test"].ToString();
                    tabTemp.TabIndex = (Int16)(i);
                    RadTabStripControl.Tabs.Add(tabTemp);

                    RadPageView pvTemp = new RadPageView();
                    pvTemp.ID = "RadPageView" + dr["Test"].ToString();
                    tabTemp.Selected = true;
                    pvTemp.Selected = true;

                    RadButton rbtn = new RadButton();
                    rbtn.Text = "RadPageView" + dr["Test"].ToString();
                    pvTemp.Controls.Add(GridTest);


                    RadMultiPageControl.PageViews.Add(pvTemp);
                }

            }
        }
```

I can see the tabs but I m not able to see the control inside tabs.

Can someone please tell me or suggest me what I m doing wrong?

Appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/tabstrip/examples/multipage/dynamic-pageview-creation/defaultcs.aspx. It explains programmatic creation of pageviews, adding controls in them. Scroll down to the code if you are not interested in the actual demo.

Comment: Also I figured out..I have to add dynamic components in OnInit event as I had multiple events firing on those control. One more thing I was adding grid  with same ID to more than one pageviews which doesn't work. So I assigned different IDs to each grid and added it to pageviews. Thanks for sharing link. It helped!